# How to send mails to 5 user per minute using Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using rails 5.

I want to send emails to 100 users from my rails application.

I have added delayed_job gem to send emails asynchronously.

Following is the code:

controller:

```
UserMailer.delay.send_mail(email, subject, body)
```

Mailer:

```
def send_mail(email, subject, body)
  mail(to: email, subject: subject, body: body, content_type: "text/html")
end
```

Q. I need to know, how to send mails to 5 user per minute?

Q. If I used delayed_job to send mails to 100 users, there are 100 jobs under delayed_job table. Can I send mail in batches?

Comment: Can you add more code from the controller, around the `UserMailer.send_mail` call? Do you have a loop around it or is it called just once? If you have all the emails before calling `send_mail` the solution should be quite simple. If, on the other hand, you need to somehow gather the emails one-by-one and then send them in batches, that's would require a completely different approach.

Comment: Fetch all users, run loop and send mails.

Comment: how to send mails to 5 user per minute?

Comment: create a new delayed job "EmailSenderJob" that gets as an input array of 20 users and repeatedly calls UserMailer.delay.send_mail(email, subject, body)
Then call EmailSenderJob 5 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to send the same subject and body to every recipient, I would use [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) and the [run_at](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#parameters) parameter.

```
# UserMailer
def send_email_batch(emails, subject, body)
  emails.each do |email|
    send_email(email, subject, body)
  end
end

# Controller
now = Time.current
User.find_in_batches(batch_size: 5).with_index do |users, batch|
  UserMailer.delay(run_at: now + batch * 60).send_email_batch(users.map(&:email), subject, body)
end
```

Comment: How to use Active Record Job feature to add emails under queue and then run it?

Comment: Have you tried writing an ActiveJob subclass? There really isn't much to do. You just have to move the `UserMailer.send_email_batch` call from the controller to the `perform` method of your Job class. Just follow the guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#creating-a-job

Comment: Ok will try. Thanks for your help.